# Entity State på VS 2012

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have just installed VS 2012.
If I add a new ADO.Net Entity Data Model och skapar en .edmx file, none of the objects in this file have an EntityState property.
Why is that?

If I set Code generation strategy property to Default (instead of None), I get the EntityState but must remove the tt files in order to be able to complie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VS2012 the default code generation strategy is to use POCO Entities and DbContext based context. This code is generated using T4 templates (i.e. tt files). If you change code generation to "Default" you will get EntityObject based entities and ObjectContext based context. This was the default behavior in VS2010. In this case there are no T4 templates and if you switch the strategy you need to remove existing T4 templates manually.